# How to transfer movie from android to ipad

Tags: ipad, video, file-transfer

I have a movie on my android external sd card. I would like to transfer it to play on my ipad. What is the simplest way to do this?

I have a very slow internet connection but both computers are on the same wireless LAN, if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

I think this can help

[image]

- Download Shareit app on both the devices.
- Click the send button on your android device and receive button on the iPad.
- Select the file you want to send and it creates an hotspot and click
  the receiver's name

Usually, this sends the files with blazing speed if it's a movie so it should be completed in 1 or 2 minutes.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Does it require an internet connection to work? Also on the ipad side, which app will it then be available to?  Just the built-in movie viewer?

Comment: no internet connection is needed

Comment: You just need an internet connection to download these apps

Comment: Sounds great. But once the file is transferred, the ipad sandboxes everything so would you be able to play the movie from a 3rd party movie player for example? For example, goodplayer.

Comment: yeah you can play it through any player on your device

Comment: let me know if this helps